# Java JTable border on the row where the mouse clicks on

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcomponent

Hey all I am trying to get this to work as I need it to. Currently it does place a red border around the row that I click on BUT once I click on a different row it goes away from the first and so on and so on.

This is what my jtable looks like:

[image]

And this is my java code that is applying the border onto the row:

```
table = new JTable(model) {
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
       Component c      = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
       JComponent jc    = (JComponent)c;
       int selCol       = table.getSelectedColumn();
       int lastRow      = table.getRowCount();

       //  Color row based on a cell value
       if (isRowSelected(row)){
           int top      = (row > 0 && isRowSelected(row - 1)) ? 1 : 2;
           int left     = column == 0 ? 2 : 0;
           int bottom   = (row < getRowCount() - 1 && isRowSelected(row + 1)) ? 1 : 2;
           int right    = column == getColumnCount() - 1 ? 2 : 0;

           jc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(top, left, bottom, right, Color.RED));                         
       }

       return c;
    }
};
```

So what is it that I am forgetting to do in order to have the row border stay a color when I move to another row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i keep a colored jTable cell colored after selecting a new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635529/how-do-i-keep-a-colored-jtable-cell-colored-after-selecting-a-new-one)

Comment: I really don't understand this requirement. Don't forget a user can use the up/down arrow on the keyboard to navigate through each row of the table. So clicking on a row should not really be doing any special processing as a table can't tell if a row was selected by mouse click or keyboard navigation. If you want the user to be able to "select" multiple for processing, then you should probably have a column with a check box that the user can click on to select the row.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing: tables can draw all their cells by reusing one single component.
Component reuse means not saving any state like border/color.

```
   if (isRowSelected(row)) {
       int top      = (row > 0 && isRowSelected(row - 1)) ? 1 : 2;
       int left     = column == 0 ? 2 : 0;
       int bottom   = (row < getRowCount() - 1 && isRowSelected(row + 1)) ? 1 : 2;
       int right    = column == getColumnCount() - 1 ? 2 : 0;

       jc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(top, left, bottom, right, Color.RED));
   } else {
       jc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
   }
```

Then there is the obvious `isRowSelected(row)`. If a click on a new row selects that row in single-selection-mode (one row only selected), then the effect would be the described. So check the selection.